# Kotlin Activity cannot be extended. This type is final, so it cannot be inherited

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have created a Kotlin Activity, but I am not able to extend the activity. I am getting this message: `This type is final, so it cannot be inherited from`. How to remove `final` from Kotlin's activity, so it can be extended?

Comment: If ones final, you shouldn't try to extend it. That would defeat the purpose of it being `final`. What class are you trying to extend?

Answer (score 89):

As per Kotlin documentation, open annotation on a class is the opposite of Java's final. It allows others to inherit from this class. By default, all classes in Kotlin are final.

```
open class Base {
    open fun v() {}
    fun nv() {}
}

class Derived() : Base() {
    override fun v() {}
}
```

Refer :https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: What is the reason for making the classes final by default in Kotlin?

Comment: @DhruvamSharma the only reason to do it was to annoy the programmers. Absolutely no other sound reason. There is a lot of discussion in Internet and most people believe it was a silly decision.

Comment: Haha , Thank you 

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to infer the answer. Wish you had given slightly more description to speed up understanding whats going on. I simply had to make my function open for the error to go away. I don't understand the discussion about classes being final or not.

Comment: @DhruvamSharma I don't know but I would guess for performance reasons. Virtual or open functions have a lot more performance overhead because it has to be looked up in a table

Comment: I vote the compiler indicate that the superclass is 'closed' rather than 'final' (a Java keyword, not a Kotlin keyword) as it makes much more sense and the solution is more clear.

Answer (score 27):

By default the Kotlin activity is final, so we cannot extend the class.
To overcome that we have to make the activity `open` so that, it can be extendable.

as like `open class BaseCompatActivity : AppCompatActivity() { }`

Answer (score 25):

In Kotlin, the classes are final by default that's why classes are not extendable.

> The open annotation on a class is the opposite of Java's final: it allows others to inherit from this class. By default, all classes in Kotlin are final.
>   [Kotlin - Inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance)

```
open class Base(p: Int)

class Derived(p: Int) : Base(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base
```

Simple add  **open** for super/parrent class:

```
open class Base
```